# Is there a way to perform "if" in python's lambda?

Tags: python, lambda, conditional-operator

In **Python 2.6**, I want to do:

```
f = lambda x: if x==2 print x else raise Exception()
f(2) #should print "2"
f(3) #should throw an exception
```

This clearly isn't the syntax. Is it possible to perform an `if` in `lambda` and if so how to do it?

Comment: You can't print or raise in a lambda. Lambdas are just functions, you can alwaya use a function instead.

Comment: I disagree with you. I need 4 different, very short functions like the one above that need to be put in a list/dictionary so I can iterate over them and select which ones to use in each iteration. Instead of many lines of code of just inits, before the iteration, itself I can bring it down to only 4 lines of init code. The less the merrier..

Comment: 4 lines of code is not a laudable solution when other people have to read, interpret, understand and maintain the code.  Further, the "print/raise" problem in the example shows this which cannot and should not be done in lambdas.

Comment: @LennartRegebro lambdas are not functions in python, they are only expressions, that is why there are many things you can not do with them.

Comment: @AaronMcMillin Lambdas are functions. They are restricted to expressions for syntax reasons, but they ARE functions.

Comment: I think the important point to make here is that lambda's aren't maintained in memory like functions, they are generic functions that are evaluated and discarded.  If you want to loop over functions you need a more permanent structure like an event.

Answer (score 890, accepted):

The syntax you're looking for:

```
lambda x: True if x % 2 == 0 else False
```

But you can't use `print` or `raise` in a lambda.

Comment: in python 3, you can use print

Comment: It's a horrible syntax--easily the worst Python language construct, approaching Perl levels of absurdity in its out-of-order evaluation--but it's what was asked for.  You're seriously voting down answers for being correct?

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: it's not the syntax that horrifying.  It's any expression of the form `True if expression else False`.  The `if` construct is totally redundant and therefore deeply and horrifyingly confusing.  It's as bad as the statement form: `if expression: return True`.

Comment: Well, it's certainly confusing if an otherwise-smart person can't realize that it's the correct answer to the question that was asked, which was entirely about syntax.  I regret that the example I has apparently given you the horrors.  Feel free to construct a more appropriate one.

Comment: @Robert Rossney: the trivial redundancy of `True if expression else False` is horrifying.  The correct form is shown by @unutbu: `lambda x: x%2==0`.  There's no horrifying `True if True else False` in that formulation.

Comment: It's the correct answer to the question "How do I write a lambda function that tells me if a number is even?"  It is not, however, a correct answer to the question that the OP originally asked.  However much you don't like the example I contrived, my post *does*, in fact, clearly answer the OP's question.

Comment: It's painfully obvious that anyone suggesting "x%2==0"--or voting up a comment recommending it, which makes at least seven people--didn't even read the original question.

Comment: @S.Lott, but if we want return something else than boolean the syntax above is required. Moreover it's the way how comprehensions currently work in Python.

Comment: @GlennMaynard I think you need to read the question. I like this answer

Comment: @recursive, how print is used in case like `df.apply(lambda x: print(x)if x.isna().sum()>0)`? Keep getting the `invalid syntax` error and can not find a solution.

Comment: You're missing `else`.  Syntax is `a if b else c`.

Answer (score 48):

why don't you just define a function?

```
def f(x):
    if x == 2:
        print(x)
    else:
        raise ValueError
```

there really is no justification to use lambda in this case.

Comment: `print` is not a function in 2.6 yet. :)

Comment: @Lukáš Lalinský: it still works in 2.x. it will be treated as a pair of redundant parentheses

Comment: You don't know his actual use case, so there's no way you can say there's no reason to use a lambda.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard:  There's almost no reason to use a lambda, period.  Assigning a lambda to a variable -- as a stand-in for `def` -- is generally a Very Bad Idea (tm).  Just use a `def` so mere mortal programmers can read, interpret, understand and maintain it.

Comment: There are plenty of legitimate uses of lambdas.  If you can't think of any, then that's not lambda's fault.  (I'm not a fan of the syntax itself, of course--it's a clumsy workaround for the fact that Python's poorly-conceived indentation syntax can't handle inline functions like normal languages.)

Comment: lambdas are most useful if you need to, for whatever reason, dynamically construct short functions or object factories at runtime. In the latter case, is probably better than `deecopy`.

Comment: I agree with Mr Maynard, a lot of people use lamda just for simplifying code, some people think they look cleaner

Answer (score 43):

Probably the worst python line I've written so far:

```
f = lambda x: sys.stdout.write(["2\n",][2*(x==2)-2])
```

If x == 2 you print,

if x != 2 you raise.

Answer (score 28):

You can easily raise an exception in a lambda, if that's what you really want to do.

```
def Raise(exception):
    raise exception
x = lambda y: 1 if y < 2 else Raise(ValueError("invalid value"))
```

Is this a good idea?  My instinct in general is to leave the error reporting out of lambdas; let it have a value of None and raise the error in the caller.  I don't think this is inherently evil, though--I consider the "y if x else z" syntax itself worse--just make sure you're not trying to stuff too much into a lambda body.

Comment: Possibly, but it depends heavily on the particular case.  Of course, you can also decorate the lambda after creating it.  `x = RaiseValueErrorOnNone(x)`, again, depending on the case.

Answer (score 21):

note you can use several *else...if* statements in your lambda definition:

```py
f = lambda x: 1 if x>0 else 0 if x ==0 else -1
```

Answer (score 16):

Lambdas in Python are fairly restrictive with regard to what you're allowed to use. Specifically, you can't have any keywords (except for operators like `and`, `not`, `or`, etc) in their body.

So, there's no way you could use a lambda for your example (because you can't use `raise`), but if you're willing to concede on that… You could use:

```
f = lambda x: x == 2 and x or None
```

Comment: lambda's specific restriction is that you are not allowed to use statements, only expressions.

Comment: Aren't lambdas meant to be short and concise else won't you write a separate function anyway?

Answer (score 4):

This snippet should help you:

```html
x = lambda age: 'Older' if age > 30 else 'Younger'

print(x(40))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you still want to print you can import future module

```
from __future__ import print_function

f = lambda x: print(x) if x%2 == 0 else False
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Logical Operators to have something like a Conditional

```
func = lambda element: (expression and DoSomething) or DoSomethingIfExpressionIsFalse
```

You can see more about Logical Operators [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/logical_operators_example.htm)

Comment: It doesn't go with python's philosophy in terms of clarity. Even though logically equivalent, the `if` syntax is always preferred over this. _The obvious_ way of checking conditions.

Comment: Thank you! I used this in a work of functional language in college because of restrictions that the professor has imposed who says that I couldn't use `if` statement, so I found this _not obvious_ way.

Answer (score 2):

the solution for the given scenerio is:

```py
f = lambda x : x if x == 2 else print("number is not 2")
f(30)  # number is not 2
f(2)   #2
```

Comment: This is valid in Python 3.x, but the question was about Python 2.6. In Python 2.x this answer is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

what you need exactly is

```
def fun():
    raise Exception()
f = lambda x:print x if x==2 else fun()
```

now call the function the way you need

```
f(2)
f(3)
```

Comment: This gives `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. I've tested this in Python 2.7 since I don't have Python 2.6 installed, but I really can't imagine this is valid in Python 2.6, since [you can't use print in a lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2970858/10669875).

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to perform an if in lambda is by using list comprehension.

You can't raise an exception in lambda, but this is a way in Python 3.x to do something close to your example:

```
f = lambda x: print(x) if x==2 else print("exception")
```

Another example:

return 1 if M otherwise 0

```
f = lambda x: 1 if x=="M" else 0
```

Comment: The question was specifically about Python 2.6, not 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution if you use Python 3.x!

```
>>> f = lambda x: print(x) if x == 2 else print("ERROR")
>>> f(23)
ERROR
>>> f(2)
2
>>>
```

Comment: This is valid in Python 3.x, but the question was about Python 2.6. In Python 2.x this answer does not work, since [you can't use print in a lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2970858/10669875).

Answer (score 0):

Following sample code works for me. Not sure if it directly relates to this question, but hope it helps in some other cases.

```
a = ''.join(map(lambda x: str(x*2) if x%2==0 else "", range(10)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help a little

you can resolve this problem in the following way

```
f = lambda x:  x==2   

if f(3):
  print("do logic")
else:
  print("another logic")
```

Answer (score 0):

it might be worth considering [np.where](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-add-column-pandas-dataframe-based-on-if-else-condition/)