# Why doesn't print work in a lambda?

Tags: python, printing, lambda, python-2.x

Why doesn't this work?

```
lambda: print "x"
```

Is this not a single statement, or is it something else?
The documentation seems a little sparse on what is allowed in a lambda...

Comment: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda.  It says "expression", which is a link to a complete definition of all possible expressions.  How is this "sparse"?  What was incorrect or incomplete?

Comment: @Lott I had misunderstanding of what expression/statement is and where print belongs.  it makes sense now

Answer (score 202, accepted):

A `lambda`'s body has to be a *single expression*. In Python 2.x, `print` is a statement. However, in Python 3, `print` is a *function* (and a function application is an expression, so it will work in a lambda). You can (and should, for forward compatibility :) use the back-ported print function if you are using the latest Python 2.x:

```
In [1324]: from __future__ import print_function

In [1325]: f = lambda x: print(x)

In [1326]: f("HI")
HI
```

Comment: Now I see why it was such a big deal to make it a function. Wanted to use print as a default kwarg and this fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: May I know why would `from __future__ import print_function` must be at the beginning of the code? thx

Comment: Where would I see the prints of what we have written here?

Comment: I agree with Ben's comment: I don't get this import. Python (2 or 3) has `print()` as built-in method.

Answer (score 28):

In cases where I am using this for simple stubbing out I use this:

```
fn = lambda x: sys.stdout.write(str(x) + "\n")
```

which works perfectly.

Comment: As an additional note - use the from future above. Use this only where that isn't available - which would be a seriously out of date version right now.

Answer (score 25):

what you've written is equivalent to

```
def anon():
    return print "x"
```

which also results in a SyntaxError, python doesn't let you assign a value to print in 2.xx; in python3 you could say

```
lambda: print('hi')
```

and it would work because they've changed print to be a function instead of a statement.

Comment: There's also `from __future__ import print_function`, which enables this in py2.x

Comment: Or alternatively `lambda: sys.stdout.write('hi')`

Comment: @fmark: Except it's not that simple in 2.x: you need to handle sys.stdout.softspace and (at least) write a newline afterwards.

Answer (score 11):

The body of a lambda has to be an expression that returns a value.  `print`, being a statement, doesn't return anything, not even `None`.  Similarly, you can't assign the result of `print` to a variable:

```
>>> x = print "hello"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    x = print "hello"
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You also can't put a variable assignment in a lambda, since assignments are statements:

```
>>> lambda y: (x = y)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    lambda y: (x = y)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 11):

You can do something like this.

**Create a function to transform print statement into a function:**

```
def printf(text):
   print text
```

**And print it:**

```
lambda: printf("Testing")
```

Comment: More flexibly: `def printf(fmt, *args): print(fmt % args)`

Answer (score 7):

With Python 3.x, print CAN work in a lambda, without changing the semantics of the lambda.

Used in a special way this is very handy for debugging.
I post this 'late answer', because it's a practical trick that I often use.

Suppose your 'uninstrumented' lambda is:

```
lambda: 4
```

Then your 'instrumented' lambda is:

```
lambda: (print (3), 4) [1]
```

Answer (score 3):

The body of a lambda has to be a single *expression*. `print` is a statement, so it's out, unfortunately.

Comment: thank you, I was not sure about definition of expression versus statement, now it makes sense

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2007-July/055260.html), you see an answer for your question.  `print` is not expression in Python, it says.

Comment: Incomplete answer, but nice link.

Answer (score 2):

in python3 print is a function, and you can print and return something as Jacques de Hooge suggests, but i like other approach: `lambda x: print("Message") or x`

`print` function returns nothing, so `None or x` code returns `x`
other way around:
 `lambda x: x or print("Message")` would print message only if x is false-ish

this is widely used in lua, and in python you can too instead of `a if cond else b` write `cond and a or b`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print something inside a lambda func In Python 3.x you can do it as following:

```
my_func = lambda : print(my_message) or (any valid expression)
```

For example:

```
test = lambda x : print(x) or x**x
```

This works because print in Python 3.x is a function.