# Python: Aliasing an If-Else conditional statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, printing

Lets say we have the following:

```
my_condition = True
print('AAA' if my_condition else 'BBB')
```

The output would be:

> AAA

---

Conversely, if `my_condition` became `False`:

```
my_condition = False
print('AAA' if my_condition else 'BBB')
```

The output would be:

> BBB

---

Now, lets say I wanted to put that same `if my_condition else 'BBB'` at the end of a bunch of different print functions.

Is there a way to alias that statement?

So instead of:

```
my_condition = True
print('AAA' if my_condition else 'BBB')
```

I wanted something like this:

```
myStatement = if my_condition else 'BBB'    

my_condition = True
print('AAA' myStatement)
```

Except, as I've already discovered, this doesn't work. 
Is it possible to alias this If-Else statement?

**Edit**
I should have mentioned that I'm running this on Python 2.7, 
however I do appreciate the 3.X solutions.

Comment: Not exactly, no.  But you can write a function that does that and then call it.

Comment: Yes, the condition will always be the same. I was trying to implement a debugging feature into my program, and I didn't certain print functions to show unless i had debugging was enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want a function, there are many ways of getting the result you want.

This one is very similar to what you've tried:

```
foo = lambda x: x if condition else "BBB"
print (foo("AAA"))
```

It's a [lambda expression](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html).

Of course you could always go with the good old fashioned function:

```
def foo(x):
    return x if condition else "BBB"
```

And another option you have (this would be my favourite):

Let's say you have a list with that bunch of words you want to print, why write than many prints? You could be using [list comprehensions](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/)

```
foo = ["hola","que","tal"];

[print(x if my_condition else "BBB") for x in foo]
```

Also if you don´t want "BBB" to be always the "else" option:

```
foo = [("hola","pues"),("que","nada"),("tal","bien")]

[print(x if my_condition else y) for (x,y) in foo]
```

[Note this won't work in Python 2.X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970858/python-lambda-with-print-statement), since `print` in 2.X is a statement and not a function.

Comment: Ups! Didn't notice that you don't want all the prints at the same time on the same place, so list comprehesions don't suit your needs, sorry.

Comment: Okay, this is really good. I tried to implement the `foo = lambda x: x if condition else "BBB" print (foo("AAA"))` but, as you predicted, it doesn't work for me in 2.X. Would there happen to be a combined 2.X/3.X solution?

Comment: That piece of code should work no matter what version you use, I meant the list comprehensions (sorry, it wasn´t clearly specified) What is the error you are getting? Anyway to make it work (in list comprehensions, as I said, the lambda expression should be working) you may use `from __future__ import print_function` to get print as a function or you could simply `import sys` and use `sys.stdout.write('hola')`

Comment: Yeah, I've tried all that. It just didn't work for me. It was okay about displaying "AAA" but the else condition just didn't work at all in 2.X. I trust that it works on 3.X, but my code isn't 3.X compatible yet.

Answer (score 5):

Use a lambda expression

```
y = lambda x: x if my_condition else 'BBB'
print(y('AAA'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If `my_condition` is always an actual `bool`, you *could* do something like

```
>>> base_case = ["BBB"]
>>> my_condition = True
>>> print((base_case + ["AAA"])[my_condition])
AAA
>>> my_condition = False
>>> print((base_case + ["AAA"])[my_condition])
BBB
```

but I would advise against it since it looks very unpythonic to me.