# Is it possible to use an inline function in a Thread call?

Tags: python, multithreading

The documentation for [`threading.Thread(target=...)`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html#thread-objects) states that

> `target` is the callable object to be invoked by the run() method.
>   Defaults to None, meaning nothing is called.

I usually use it like this:

```
import threading

def worker():
    a = 3
    print("bonjour {a}".format(a=a))

threading.Thread(target=worker).start()
```

**Is there a way to chain the function elements in `target` so that a new one does not need to be defined?** Something like (pseudocode obviously)

```
threading.Thread(target=(a=3;print("bonjour {a}".format(a=a))).start()
```

I have a bunch of very short calls to make in the `Thread` call and would like to avoid multiplication of function definitions.

Comment: What do you have against defining a function?

Comment: Nothing, and this is how I do it today. In one case, though, I have 10 different two liners (so I cannot use a lambda, per @ForceBru answer) and the code would be more compact and organized without them floating around.

Comment: Your code is more testable (you have tests, right?) if you define a function to use as the target of the thread.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a lambda function in Python 3.x

```
import threading

threading.Thread(target=lambda a: print("Hello, {}".format(a)), args=(["world"]))
```

You should probably take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2970858/4354477) to see why you can't use `print` in Python 2.x in lambda expressions.

---

Actually, you *can* fit many function calls into your `lambda`:

```
from __future__ import print_function # I'm on Python 2.7
from threading import Thread

Thread(target=(lambda: print('test') == print('hello'))).start()
```

That will print both `test` and `hello`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I am removing my previous comment about the problem with many functions within a `lambda` which your update addresses perfectly.

Comment: Actually, `or` would not be a good idea, because if the first function returned something that has a boolean value of true, the second function will not be evaluated, and hence will not be called.

Answer (score 6):

I don't really like using `exec`, but in Python3.x it is a function, so you *could* do

```
threading.Thread(target=exec, args=('a=3; print("bonjour {a}".format(a=a))',)
```