# RDD foreach method provides no results

Tags: apache-spark, foreach, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to understand how `foreach` method works. In my jupyter notebook, I tried :

```python
def f(x): print(x)
a = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = a.foreach(f)
print(type(b))
<class 'NoneType'>
```

I can execute that without any problem, but I don't have any output except the `print(type(b))` part. The `foreach` doesn't return anything, just a none type. I do not know what `foreach` is supposed to do, and how to use it. Can you explain me what it is used for ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foreach` is an action, and does not return anything; so, you cannot use it as you do, i.e. assigning it to another variable like  `b = a.foreach(f)`. From [Learning Spark](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/), p. 41-42:

[image]

[image]

Adapting the simple example [from the docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.foreach), run in a PySpark terminal:

```python
>>> def f(x): print(x)
>>> a = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> a.foreach(f)
5
4
3
1
2
```

(NOTE: not sure about Jupyter, but the above code will not produce any print results in a Databricks notebook.)

You may also find the answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41388597/difference-between-rdd-foreach-and-rdd-map) helpful.

Comment: appart from `print`, do you have any other concret usecase ?

Comment: @Steven No. My feeling is that it is not widely used, apart from cases such the ones described in the book excerpt above.

Answer (score 1):

I just use the following method and it is working perfectly under Jupyter Notebook with PySpark:

```
for row in RDD.toLocalIterator():
    print(row)
```

Actually it will convert your RDD into a generator object and then by using this generator object you can easily iterate over each element. OR you can first create a generator object and then use it in your loop like below:

```
genobj = data.toLocalIterator()
for row in genobj:
    print(row)
```