# Lambda invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

This:

```
add = lambda x, y: x += y
```

Gives:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

My task is to be able to mullitply or add every number between 1-513 with 1 function and 2 lambda functions. So if you have any suggestions that'll help.

Comment: `x += y` is a statement, not an expression. `lambda`s can only contain expressions. Try `lambda x, y: x+y` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't print work in a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970858/why-doesnt-print-work-in-a-lambda)

Answer (score 3):

As everybody said, you should put an expression not a statement in lambda body, Maybe this will help you:

```
from functools import reduce

add = lambda x,y: reduce(lambda i,j:i+j, range(x,y))
```

for `mul`:

```
mult = lambda x,y: reduce(lambda i,j:i*j, range(x,y))
```

or you can go without `reduce`, for `add` :

```
add = lambda x,y: sum(range(x,y))
```

also, you can use `operator` like this:

```
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce
mult = lambda x,y: reduce(mul, range(x,y), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

For continued multiplication, this works:

```
f = lambda n1, n2: n2 * (f(n1, n2-1) if n2 > 1 else 1)
print('f(1, 5) =', f(1, 5))
```

This output:

```
f(1, 5) = 120
```

(1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120)