# May I know how to deal with if not p, if p kind of if-elif-else question?

Tags: python, if-statement

The question is as follows:

```
def p():
    return lambda: print("Confused?")
if not p:
    p()
elif p:
    p()()
else:
    print(not p()())
```

I dont understand how to get Confused? as the answer

Comment: print it one by one you will understand

Comment: Can you explain what this is supposed to do and how it is supposed to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't print work in a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970858/why-doesnt-print-work-in-a-lambda)