# how to print the letter if it exists in the list using lambda,filter function

Tags: python, list, lambda, filterfunction

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
list(filter(lambda x : print(x) if 'e' in x ,letters))
```

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: try `[x for x in letters if x == 'e']` it will print `e` if present else empty list

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: based on the title, just do `print("e" in letters)`, not sure why you need to complicate this

Comment: that's not a valid ternary operation, it should be `smt1 if condition else smt2`

Comment: @matiiss I wanted to try wether it is possible or not .

Comment: a lot of things are possible, it doesn't mean you always need to choose complicated ways of achieving them...

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this "invalid syntax" error because you are applying filter for list letters. For `x=="e"` or `"e" in x` you are returning item of list as it is but for other value you have to return something.

You can **add else condition** like below:

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
list(filter((lambda x : x if 'e'==x else None),letters))
```

Output:

```
['e']
```

if you use jupyter you will get this as output otherwise you have to print that list.

For printing directly you can do this:

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
d = list(filter((lambda x : print(x) if 'e'==x else None),letters))
```

Output:

```
e
```

I hope I understood your question properly.

Other reference for printing in lambda [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda),  [Why doesn't print work in a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970858/why-doesnt-print-work-in-a-lambda)

**Conclusion:** "Add else condition for `if 'e' not in x`"

Comment: Thank you I was able to understand the solution provided