# Map an if statement in Python

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, functional-programming

I'm trying to map the following function over a pandas dataframe (basically a list) in python 2.7:

```
df["Cherbourg"] = df["Embarked"].map(lambda x: if (x == "C") 1 else 0)
```

But python errors saying using a lambda function like this is a syntax error. Is there some way to map an if statement like this in python?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try

```
lambda x: 1 if x == "C" else 0
```

possible duplicate of
[Is there a way to perform "if" in python's lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585322/is-there-a-way-to-perform-if-in-pythons-lambda)

Example :

```
map(lambda x: True if x % 2 == 0 else False, range(1, 11))
```

result will be - [False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True]

Answer (score 5):

It will be simpler to just do this:

```
df["Cherbourg"] = (df["Embarked"] == "C").astype('int)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df["Cherbourg"] = df["Embarked"].apply(lambda x:1 if x == 'C' else 0)
```

Comment: This solution may work but please add some explanation to support this code solution. Also, please format the code inside backticks (`\``)

Comment: I doubt that this helps or even works at all. Would you like to add an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

A more readable approach:

```
def mapping(row):
    if row.Embarked == 'C':
        row.Cherbourg = 1
    else:
        row.Cherbourg = 0
return row
    
df.apply(mapping, axis='columns')
```