# lambda function with multiple ifs using pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a simple df with revenue and cost figures. The cost can be negative in my case.

I want to compute the revenue to cost ratio as follows:

```
if ((x['cost'] < 0) & (x['rev'] >=0 )):
   x['r_c_ratio'] = (x['rev'] + abs(x['cost'])) / abs(x['cost'])
elif((x['cost'] > 0) & (x['rev'] <=0 )):
   x['r_c_ratio'] = (x['cost'] + abs(x['rev'])) / x['cost']
else:
   x['r_c_ratio'] = x['rev'] / x['cost']
```

How does one implement this in a lambda function?

```
df['revenue_cost_ratio'] = df.apply(lambda x:....
```

According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585322/is-there-a-way-to-perform-if-in-pythons-lambda) the lambda syntax is:

```
lambda x: True if x % 2 == 0 else False
```

This only allows one else condition.

Comment: This is unrelated to your question about creating a `lambda` function, but `&` is the bitwise-and operator in Python. You want the `and` operator when you're doing a logical-and (which appears to be what you want here). The two operators do work the same for the Boolean values `True` and `False`, but won't always do the same thing if you have other "truthy" values involved in the operaton (e.g. compare `1 & 2` with `1 and 2`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***pandas vectorized***

```
r = x.rev.div(x.cost)
r.abs().add(r < 0).rename('revenue_cost_ratio')
```

***numpy vectorized***
by the way, I'd use this one

```
r = x.rev.values / x.cost.values
pd.Series(np.abs(r) + (r < 0), x.index, name='revenue_cost_ratio')
```

***if you insist on a lambda***

```
f = lambda x: (x.rev * x.cost < 0) + abs(x.rev / x.cost)
x['revenue_cost_ratio'] = x.apply(f)
```

Let's look at your 3 cases

***Case 1***

```
if ((x['cost'] < 0) & (x['rev'] >=0 )):
   x['r_c_ratio'] = (x['rev'] + abs(x['cost'])) / abs(x['cost'])
```

when `x['cost'] < 0`, `abs(x['cost'])` is just `-1 * x['cost']` so this can be simplified to

```
(x['rev'] - x['cost']) / -x['cost']
```

or

```
(x['cost'] - x['rev']) / x['cost']
```

***Case 2***

```
elif((x['cost'] > 0) & (x['rev'] <=0 )):
   x['r_c_ratio'] = (x['cost'] + abs(x['rev'])) / x['cost']
```

when `x['rev'] <= 0`, `abs(x['rev'])` is just `-1 * x['rev']` so this can be simplified to

```
(x['cost'] - x['rev']) / x['cost']
```

Wow this is the same as case one!  But we can reduce this further to

```
1 - x['rev'] / x['cost']
```

And when do we use it?  Seems only when either `x['rev']` or `x['cost']` is negative but not both.  Well, that only occurs when that ratio is negative.

***Case 3***

```
x['rev'] / x['cost']
```

Again!  What luck!  This looks a lot like `1 - x['rev'] / x['cost']`

So if we pre-calculate `x['rev'] / x['cost']`, test it for negativity and return it or 1 less it, we are good.  Hence the functions in the beginning.

Comment: Good explanation. How do I give you bounty on this ? :P

Comment: Can't put a bounty on until 2 days.  Not necessary but I appreciate the gesture (of course, I can't stop you if you insist :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use apply. It is extremely slow. Use a nested where.

```
np.where((x['cost'] < 0) & (x['rev'] >=0 ),  (x['rev'] + abs(x['cost'])) / abs(x['cost']),
    np.where((x['cost'] > 0) & (x['rev'] <=0 ), (x['cost'] + abs(x['rev'])) / x['cost'], 
             x['rev'] / x['cost']))
```