# Adding multiple expressions to lambda function, to get if/else output

Tags: python

I am a new to programming, and was looking for some help with adding multiple expressions to a lambda function. But cannot seem to get to work. It's a noob level problem, so can please some one help me out?

```
a = int()
b = int()

greater (a,b) = lambda(a,b): (a > b) == 'a' or (b > a) == 'b' :

print (greater(10,9))
```

Comment: Keep in mind this violates the Python style guide (PEP8). At this point you might as well define this function with `def`

Comment: hi, i understand def is the way to go. I was just going through the concept of lambda functions, and wanted to perform a simple operation.

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda)

Comment: See also [Is there a way to perform “if” in python's lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585322/is-there-a-way-to-perform-if-in-pythons-lambda)

Answer (score 3):

You *can* achieve this using an `if` condition (which will not "catch" the case `a` and `b` are equal):

```
greater = lambda a, b: 'a' if a > b else 'b'
```

Catching the equality case is a bit tricker and requires nested `if`:

```
greater = lambda a, b: 'a' if a > b else 'b' if b > a else 'N/A'
```

(Note that there are no parenthesis after `greater` and around the lambda's arguments)

**However**, this violates the Python style guide (PEP8). At this point (where you already named the lambda), you should just define this function with `def`.

Comment: I'd rather specify this as a `ternary operation` of some sorts... a traditional if statement does not operate this way and doesn't return a value

Comment: hi i just executed your expression, but it's still giving me a syntax error. ok I'll tell you the actual question.Create a lambda function 'greater', which takes two arguments x and y and return x if x>y otherwise y.

Comment: in the second case I would use brackets, otherwise it is not obvious which condition executes first

Comment: @Dan Since this piece of code shouldn't be used anyway, I don't think that really matters

Comment: @MZ I'm not sure what you mean by "a traditional if statement does not operate this way and doesn't return a value"

Comment: @DeepSpace can you help me out with this question. Create a lambda function 'greater', which takes two arguments x and y and return x if x>y otherwise y. what would coding look like ?

Comment: @neo_jr that is almost exactly what the code in this answer is doing, except that it returns the literal strings `'a'` and `'b'` (instead of `a` and `b`, respectively. It should be straightforward what needs to be changed

Comment: @MZ I'm aware of the differences, just don't understand what you meant by saying that `if` conditions don't "operate this way". What does "this" refer to?

Comment: @DeepSpace if statements are for branching, the expression of an if statement does not return a value

Comment: @MZ Try this code, it works as intended... BTW, as for your last suggestion, at this point you can just do `greater = max` but clearly that is not the intention

Comment: @DeepSpace ok. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions

Comment: @DeepSpace yes, it that lambda form and it was not sufficing my needs. like you have suggested, i removed the quotes, and it did work. Also, can you please give me hint, as to why the else 'N/A' was necessary, because i removed it and ran the code, but it gave a syntax error.