# What is the correct lambda for the following projecting function?

Tags: python

The following code does not compile.

```
data = [5, 3, 2, 4, 1]   

def projector(x):
    if (x % 2) == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0    

# evens = map(projector, data)
evens = map(lambda x: if (x % 2) == 0: 1 else: 0, data)
print(list(evens))
```

#### Question

What is the correct lambda that is equivalent to `projector` above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to perform "if" in python's lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585322/is-there-a-way-to-perform-if-in-pythons-lambda)

Comment: In this case you can do `lambda x: (x + 1) % 2` without needing a conditional, but for a general answer see the linked duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [ternary operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Python)

You want:

`res = 0 if (x % 2) == 0 else 1`

That you can map this way:

`evens = map(lambda x: 0 if (x % 2) == 0 else 1, data)`